# how to perform a combination procedure on a vector such that i have the original vector as the first row

Tags: r, vector, combinations

I have this vector

```
 b=c(5,8,9)
```

I want to perform a combination on b selecting 2 items at a time such that i have the original elements of b as my first row to get

```
        [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    5     8    9
[2,]    8     9    5
```

I tried combn(b, 2) and it gives me this

```
        [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    5     5    8
[2,]    8     9    9
```

Can i get help to achieve my desired result?

Comment: These are permutations as order matters. What you are observing with `combn(b, 2)` is all combinations of `b` choose 2. There just happens to be 3 such combinations: `(5, 8), (5, 9), (8, 9)`. The output is a column wise matrix.

Comment: Also, is this `R`? If so, you should add the `r` tag.

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. If you need the first row to be the original values, then you don't really want to pick *2* items - you want to use the first value, then pick (sample) *1* of the other two values? so your matrix should have the first row as 5, 8, 9, and the second row as (8 or 9), (5 or 9), (5 or 8)?

Comment: Yes you are right Tyler, i need my output as   
 (5     8    9) maps to (  8     9    5 )  or  (5  8  9 ) maps to ( 9   5  8).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the second row of your desired result is not uniquely defined, there is no need for any sophisticated tools:

```
b <- 1:10
rbind(b, c(b[-1], b[1]))
#   [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
# b    1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9    10
#      2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9   10     1
```

In this case I only "shift" `b` by one position in the second row, which indeed results in a permutation. I'm assuming that the elements of `b` don't repeat.

Comment: @user3327637, does it answer your question?